# Java Spark - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded - Large Dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark

We have a spark SQL query that returns over 5 million rows. Collecting them all for processing results in java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded (eventually). Here's the code:

```
final Dataset<Row> jdbcDF = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc")
            .option("url", "xxxx")
            .option("driver", "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver")
            .option("query", sql)
            .option("user", "xxxx")
            .option("password", "xxxx")
            .load();
    final Encoder<GdxClaim> gdxClaimEncoder = Encoders.bean(GdxClaim.class);
    final Dataset<GdxClaim> gdxClaimDataset = jdbcDF.as(gdxClaimEncoder);
    System.out.println("BEFORE PARALLELIZE");
    final JavaRDD<GdxClaim> gdxClaimJavaRDD = javaSparkContext.parallelize(gdxClaimDataset.collectAsList());
    System.out.println("AFTER");
    final JavaRDD<ClaimResponse> gdxClaimResponse = gdxClaimJavaRDD.mapPartitions(mapFunc);
    mapFunc = (FlatMapFunction<Iterator<GdxClaim>, ClaimResponse>) claim -> {
        System.out.println(":D " + claim.next().getRBAT_ID());
        if (claim != null && !currentRebateId.equals((claim.next().getRBAT_ID()))) {
            if (redisCommands == null || (claim.next().getRBAT_ID() == null)) {
                    serObjList = Collections.emptyList();
                } else {

                    generateYearQuarterKeys(claim.next());

                    redisBillingKeys = redisBillingKeys.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
                    final String[] stringArray = redisBillingKeys.toArray(new String[redisBillingKeys.size()]);
                    serObjList = redisCommands.mget(stringArray);

                    serObjList = serObjList.stream().filter(clientObj -> clientObj.hasValue()).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    deserializeClientData(serObjList);
                    currentRebateId = (claim.next().getRBAT_ID());
            }
        }
        return (Iterator) racAssignmentService.assignRac(claim.next(), listClientRegArr);

    };
```

You can ignore most of this, the line that runs forever and never can return is:

```
final JavaRDD<GdxClaim> gdxClaimJavaRDD = javaSparkContext.parallelize(gdxClaimDataset.collectAsList());
```

Because of: 
    gdxClaimDataset.collectAsList()

We are unsure where to go from here and totally stuck. Can anyone help? We've looked everywhere for some example to help.

Comment: Here's a guide to help: https://www.baeldung.com/java-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

Comment: I realize this isn't very helpful, but if you can't store the query result in your allocated amount of RAM, you shouldn't make the query in the first place.

Comment: hey! i might be misunderstanding but i see that you are parallelizing after doing a collect. This part -> since you already have the data in executors , why are you collecting and then parallelizing it. Just do the processing on top of the dataset itself or convert it directly into RDD and then process as it is.

Comment: Kartik, are you talking about this line? final JavaRDD<GdxClaim> gdxClaimJavaRDD = javaSparkContext.parallelize(gdxClaimDataset.collectAsList());  Even if we do gdxClaimDataset.collectAsList() and process on top of it, gdxClaimDataset fills up with too much data and it runs out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace this line :

```
final JavaRDD<GdxClaim> gdxClaimJavaRDD = javaSparkContext.parallelize(gdxClaimDataset.collectAsList());
```

with :

```
final JavaRDD<GdxClaim> gdxClaimJavaRDD = gdxClaimDataset.javaRDD();
```

Comment: It looks like this is going to get us on the right track. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

At a high level, [`collectAsList()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#collectAsList()) is going to bring your entire dataset into memory, and this is what you need to avoid doing.

You may want to look at the [Dataset docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html) in general (same link as above). They explain its behavior, including the [javaRDD()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#collectAsList()) method, which is probably the way to avoid `collectAsList()`.

Keep in mind: other "terminal" operations, that collect your dataset into memory, will cause the same problem. The key is to filter down to your small subset, whatever that is, either before or during the process of collection.